# Dictionary with for...in... in it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am looking at someone else's code to adapt it for my own [here](https://gist.github.com/sloria/6407257), and I came across this in line 44:

```
scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
```

When I try this in Python 2.7.6, I get a syntax error in the space after the word `for`. Why is in invalid syntax and what exactly is going on here in the code?

Comment: This is equivalent to `dict((word, tfidf(word, blob, bloblist)) for word in blob.words)`

Comment: That code works fine for me. Are you sure you ran this on Python 2.7? A dict-comprehension will raise SyntaxError in Python 2.6 or earlier but not in 2.7+.'

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I am on 2.7, but it might just be an out of date sublime text plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary comprehension was [backported only to 2.7 not to 2.6, from 3.1](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features)

> Dictionary and set comprehensions ({ i: i*2 for i in range(3)}).

So, the equivalent in Python 2.6 would be,

```
dict((word, tfidf(word, blob, bloblist)) for word in blob.words)
```

But passing a list would be slightly faster,

```
dict([(word, tfidf(word, blob, bloblist)) for word in blob.words])
```